# RxJs allow first n requests and then delay

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I want to request `n` records from a service with an `Observable` interface using RxJs. The service has a DDoS protection mechanism, so if I instantly request i.e. 1000 records, I will get blocked for a few minutes.

I put a static delay of 1 second on each record as below:

---

```
    Observable.from(users.map((x, i) => ({unwrap: x, index: i}) ))
      .concatMap(i => Observable.of(i).delay(1000))
      .combineLatest(tokenObs)
      .flatMap(res => {
        let [val, token] = res;
        return this.userByIdentifierService.getUserByIdentifier(token, val.unwrap.user.Id)
          .flatMap(user => this.shipByUserService.getShipByUser(user.user))
          .map(ship => ({index: val.index, ship: ship}));
      })
      .do(res => this.users[res.index].ship = res.ship)
```

---

I would like to speed up the perceived performance of the UI.

I was wondering if there was an elegant way to take the first i.e. 10 records without any wait time, and then only add the delay for records exceeding that number?

So intended behavior is:
first 10 records => no delay, after 10 records => 1 second delay between

Using typescript w/ RxJS via Angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you...

```js
Observable
  .from(users.map((x, i) => ({unwrap: x, index: i}) ))
  .concatMap(i => i.index < 10 ? i : Observable.of(i).delay(1000))
;
```

Comment: This is a lot better than the solution I came up with, thank you! I posted my solution below for non-indexed data :)

Comment: To typecheck this must be: .concatMap(i => i.index < 10 ? Observable.of(i) : Observable.of(i).delay(1000))

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use underscores throttle function to achieve this along with a request counter to determine if you should use the throttled call or the un-throttled call.
Something like the below should get you started.

```
 const throttled = _.throttle(this.userByIdentifierService.getUserByIdentifier, 1000);
 let firstCall = true;
 Observable.from(users.map((x, i) => ({unwrap: x, index: i}) ))
   .concatMap(i => Observable.of(i).delay(1000))
   .combineLatest(tokenObs)
   .flatMap(res => {
      let [val, token] = res;
      if(firstCall){
        return this.userByIdentifierService.getUserByIdentifier(token, val.unwrap.user.Id)
         .flatMap(user => this.shipByUserService.getShipByUser(user.user))
        .map(ship => ({index: val.index, ship: ship}));
       } else {
       throttled(token, val.unwrap.user.id).flatMap(user => this.shipByUserService.getShipByUser(user.user)).map(ship => ({index: val.index, ship}));
       }
    })
  .do(res => this.users[res.index].ship = res.ship)
```

Read more on the throttle method  -- [Underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle)

Comment: `I would personally use underscores throttle` => [RXJS Throttle](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md)

Comment: Thanks, but `throttle` and `delay` both have a static time to wait. I want to emit the first 10 or so elements with no delay, and then start throttling. I've been trying to use a concat of two streams along the lines of '.let(j => {
            return Observable.concat([
              j.take(10),
              j.delay(1000)
            ])' but haven't been able to make it typecheck yet

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Hitmands is better if the data is indexed. Here's a solution I came up with that works for non-indexed data.

```
Observable.from(users.map((x, i) => ({unwrap: x, index: i}) ))
  //.concatMap(i => Observable.of(i).delay(1000))
  .let(j => j.take(10).concat(
            j.skip(10).concatMap(i => Observable.of(i).delay(1000))))
  .do(s => console.log('fetching', s.index))
```

It also occured to me later that you can approach this problem using a linearly increasing delay i.e.

```
 .concatMap(i => Observable.of(i).delay(Math.min(50 + i.index * 25, 1000)))
```